# what is the best protocol for sql server express 2008 r2 client and server running on same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

We use sql express 2008 r2 for simple reporting and data storage. Data is written typically at the rate of 600 to 3000 records per minute. (one client one connection same machine). We need the optimal performing protocol. (good performance without hogging memory..) I read articles online and they are quite confusing when it comes to deciding between tcp/ip, shared mem and named pipes. To summarize msdn documentation

1) Shared memory has no configurable properties. Shared memory is always tried first, and cannot be moved from the top position of the Enabled Protocols list in the Client Protocols Properties list. `Does this mean shared mem is preferred and fastest ?`

2)For TCP/IP Sockets, data transmissions are more streamlined and have less overhead. Data transmissions can also take advantage of TCP/IP Sockets performance enhancement mechanisms such as windowing, delayed acknowledgements, and so on. ok. But `is it faster than shared mem ?`

3)If the server application is running locally on the computer running an instance of Microsoft® SQL Server™ , the local Named Pipes protocol is an option. `Local named pipes runs in kernel mode and is extremely fast.` When I read this I could not take the confusion anymore and decided to post my question on stack.

So sql Gurus please help me decide. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Shared Memory is the fastest protocol, however if "performance" is your goal, the framework you use to access the database and how you transfer the data in, the sql query you write (or use another method) will all have a much bigger impact on performance.

If you are going to try and use ADO/ADO.NET or another heavy protocol like this most performance will be lost here. If extreme performance is what you are after you'll need to investigate and learn how to communicate with the database engine on a lower level.

See http://www.devart.com/sdac/ as a start.

Answer (score 1):

If the following quote from your answer is actually correct then you your question already contains the answer:

> Shared memory is always tried first, and cannot be moved from the top position of the Enabled Protocols list in the Client Protocols Properties list.

Given that your client and database are running on the same machine this means that shared memory will always work (without drastic measures that is).  It doesn't matter what protocol you chooe to use - shared memory **is** the one that will end up being used! :-)

For what its worth the performance completely depends on the implementation used within SQL Server (I'm basing this on my knowledge of the communication methods rather than intimate knowledge of SQL Server), but the order (in terms of performance) almost certainly goes like this (fastest first):

- Shared memory (backed up by the fact that SQL Server always uses this when it can)
- Named pipes
- TCP/IP

I can't find any citation that Shared memory actually **is** faster than named pipes, but TBH I don't think it matters that much - communication between client and database on a local machine will be incredibly efficient anyway, I doubt that you would be able to notice any performance difference.

Comment: Yes. But if named pipes is faster and has less memory overhead I can Disable shared memory (Right click disable in configuration manager).

Comment: @Gullu Ah, I hadn't twigged that you could turn it off, but yes I would expect that shared memory is fastest although I can find no citation for this.